# Apex:enhancedList on change page size

Tags: visualforce, enhancedlist

When Salesforce use standard ListView for objects it adjusts it's size to screen.

[image]

When I add apex:EnhancedList for same object I have to fill height parameter and as result unable adjust my page to the screen.

[image]

Could you please advise if there is any possibility with apex, javascript or css 
adjust apex: enhanced list to page.

My Visualforce markup is very simple:

```
<apex:page standardController="Scanned_Payable_Invoice__c" recordSetVar="ConfirmedRecords" tabStyle="Scanned_Payable_Invoice__c" docType="html-5.0" >
    <apex:enhancedList type="Scanned_Payable_Invoice__c" id="ScannedInvoiceEnhancedList" height="775"/>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem resolved with help of JavaScript.

Created function where I'am looking for my Enhanced list in ListViewport object then check what is current height of the inner Screen ans set my height as inner -130, because of headers.

Then I set my function **Resizer()** on window resize listener. And also load function on the page load.

```
<apex:page standardController="Scanned_Payable_Invoice__c" recordSetVar="ConfirmedRecords" tabStyle="Scanned_Payable_Invoice__c" docType="html-5.0" >

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function Resizer() {
        var iName='';
        for (let key of Object.keys(ListViewport.instances)) {  
            iName = key;
            if (iName.indexOf('ScannedInvoiceEnhancedList') >=0) {
                break;    
            }    
        }
        var wh=window.innerHeight;
        ListViewport.instances[iName]['height']=wh-130;
    }

    window.addEventListener("resize", Resizer);

    </script>

    <apex:enhancedList type="Scanned_Payable_Invoice__c" id="ScannedInvoiceEnhancedList" height="775"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Resizer();
    </script>

</apex:page>
```

Works perfectly!!!

Answer (score 1):

Enhanced List exposes binds its own JavaScript API to `this` scope via the `oncomplete` attribute:

```
<apex:enhancedList
    type="Lead"
    height="600"
    onComplete="try {this.vf = this.height = null; this.resize();} catch (e) {}"
/>
```

(Not recommended as the API is undocumented)

[image: ListViewport-API]

Comment: still works in 2021.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [`<apex:enhancedList>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_enhancedList.htm) tag has a `rowsPerPage` attribute you can use. You're just going to have to set it to a lower value or adjust the `height` if you want this component to take up less vertical space. There's no way to do it dynamically without digging deep into the stylesheet and overriding Salesforce default styling.

> **Attribute Name**
> rowsPerPage
>
> **Attribute Type**
> Integer
>
> **Description**
> An integer value that specifies the number of rows per page. The default value is the preference of the current user. Possible values are 10, 25, 50, 100, 200. Note: If you set the value for greater than 100, a message is automatically displayed to the user, warning of the potential for performance degradation.

Comment: I don't want to override Salesforce styles, even opposite I would like to use same style that Salesforce uses for standard ListViews from the first screenshot.

Comment: @Mike You're just going to have to lower the `rowsPerPage` then. I don't think adjusting the styles is very feasible, nor reasonable.